# Как посчитать максимальное произведение цифр в каждой строке матрицы?

Tags: python, tkinter

Мне нужно посчитать произведения цифр элементов матрицы каждой строки и вывести наибольшее произведение в дополнительном столбце справа от матрицы. При подсчёте произведения получаются странные значения, как пофиксить?
P.s. имеется ввиду нужно брать каждый элемент в строке матрицы, считать произведение его цифр, а затем сравнить с произведениями полученными из других элементов матрицы этой же строки, находить большее и выводить в столб справа от матрицы. Далее цикл переходит к следующей строке.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('800x600')

c = Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg='white')
c.place(x=0, y=0)

stolbi = 0

def getting1():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 6
    print(stolbi)

def getting2():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 7
    print(stolbi)

def getting3():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 8
    print(stolbi)

def getting4():
    global stolbi
    stolbi = 9
    print(stolbi)

def CurSelect(event):
    global valuestrok
    valuestrok=int(stroki_listbox.get(stroki_listbox.curselection()))
    print(valuestrok)



#Создание ListBox
stroki = [6,7,8,9]
stroki_listbox = Listbox(width = 10, height = 4, font = 'TimesNewRoman 14', highlightcolor = 'blue')
for number in stroki:
    stroki_listbox.insert(END, number)

stroki_listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', CurSelect)
stroki_listbox.place(x=500,y=150)

#Создание радиокнопок
r_var = BooleanVar()
r_var.set(0)
r1 = Radiobutton(text='6', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=1, width = 15, command = getting1)
r1.place(x=500,y=300)

r2 = Radiobutton(text='7', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=2, width = 15, command = getting2)
r2.place(x=500,y=325)

r3 = Radiobutton(text='8', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=3, width = 15, command = getting3)
r3.place(x=500,y=350)

r4 = Radiobutton(text='9', indicatoron = 0, variable=r_var, value=4, width = 15, command = getting4)
r4.place(x=500,y=375)

t1 = c.create_text(585, 100, text = 'Выберите кол-во строк:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
t2 = c.create_text(600, 270, text = 'Выберите кол-во столбцов:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')


m = []
list1 = []
def start(event):
    
    global y_coords, x_coords, m, list1

    #Матрица
    
    y_coords = 0
    m = [] # объявление массива, сначала как одномерного
    c.delete('all')
    t1 = c.create_text(585, 100, text = 'Выберите кол-во строк:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
    t2 = c.create_text(600, 270, text = 'Выберите кол-во столбцов:', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
    for i in range(valuestrok): #цикл по строкам
        m.append([]) # добавление второй размерности массива
        y_coords += 50 # смещение очередной строки матрицы вниз по вертикали
        x_coords  = 0 # начальные значения координат Х элементов матрицы на канве
        for j in range(stolbi): # цикл по столбцам матрицы
            ct = random.randint(-100, 100) # генерация целого случайного числа в диапазоне -100 до 100
            m[i].append(ct) # добавление сгенерированного числа в матрицу
            x_coords += 40 # смещение очередного элемента матрицы вправо по горизонтали
            c.create_text(x_coords, y_coords, text = ct) # вывод на канву очередного элемента матрицы

    #Наибольшее произведение цифр в элементах каждой строки
    y_coords = 0
    mult = 1
    i = 0  # Номер столбца
    list1 = []
    
    while i != valuestrok:
        y_coords += 50
        for j in range(stolbi):
            a = int(m[i][j])
            for k in str(abs(a)):
                while int(k) > 0:
                    digit = int(k) % 10
                    mult = mult * digit
                    k = int(k) // 10
                    
        list1.append(mult)
        print(mult)
        c.create_text(400, y_coords, text=mult, font='Times 11')
        mult = 1
        i = i + 1


c.bind("<Button-2>", start) #запуск программы на колесо мыши
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Очень рекомендуется: 1) Приводить минимальный код. Например, `tkinter` точно влияет или и без него проблема такая же? 2) Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Например:
Вход: матрица 3 x 3, её элементы построчно [12,13,14],[24,25,26],[34,35,36].
Выход: 1-строка макс. произв. цифр = 4, 2-строка = 12, 3-строка = 18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для примера который вы указали в комментариях, сработает такой код

Про [reduce](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-functools-python/funktsija-reduce-modulja-functools/)

```py
from functools import reduce

lst = [[12,13,14],[24,25,26],[34,35,36]]

for x in lst:
  mx = float("-inf")
  for n in x:
    mx = max(mx, int(reduce(lambda x,y: int(x) * int(y), str(n))))
  x.append(mx)

print(lst)
# [[12, 13, 14, 4], [24, 25, 26, 12], [34, 35, 36, 18]]
```

UPD: для отрицательных чисел доработка во втором цикле

```py
  for n in x:
    n = list(str(n))
    if "-" in n:
      n[0] = n[0]+n.pop()
    mx = max(mx, int(reduce(lambda x,y: int(x) * int(y), n)))
  x.append(mx)
```

Comment: Да, сработает, но нужно понимать, что число может лежать в диапазоне от -100 до 100, как я писал выше. Насколько я понимаю будет ошибка если, например, будет число 100?

Comment: @ProFirtos при числе 100 ошибки не будет, при отрицательных числах да, сейчас подправлю

Comment: @ProFirtos обновил

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает почти как надо, я добавил во тором цикле модуль числа и теперь всё отлично.
`n = list(str(abs(n)))`